# Can I monitor my guest's activity without them knowing? They know how to delete browsing history

Tags: windows-7, tracking

Is there a way for me to monitor the activity of a "Guest" on my computer? They know how to delete their browsing history, although they have missed a few.

I need to see what sites they are visiting, and who they are communicating with. If I put a password on the "Guest" account, I'll be the one inconvenienced. This person does need access to the computer in general, so I can't just lock them out. Instead I would like to be able to verify their activities.

Is this possible? Can I do this within Windows?

Comment: I think your problem is a personal issue, not a technical one. That said, I suggest you do some research and look for parental control software, if you're intent on doing such tracking.

Comment: If you don't trust them don't let them use your PC! Spying is an ugly business.

Comment: @Ben N: Thanks for expressing my thoughts so clearly - I couldn't properly express them.

Comment: It would be unethical to help you monitor someone without their knowledge or consent.

Comment: Yes it is a personal issue, thank you for pointing that out. But it is a matter of me protecting myself, or putting someone on the street in the middle of winter. I think I'm protecting both of us!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by using *Activity Reports* on Windows. This is done trough the Windows Parental Control feature. Take a look at the following links for further details:

[Windows Live Family Safety](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/looking-for-web-filtering-and-activity-reports-in-windows-parental-controls) is a service provider (add-on) for Windows Parental Controls that will give you the ability to get *Activity Reports*. However it is not included by default, so you need to add itmanually.

The steps to add a service provider to Windows Parental Controls are given [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/how-can-i-add-additional-parental-controls).

Comment: Thank you for your non judgmental answer to my question. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your firewall to log outgoing requests from certain software, and/or watch certain outgoing ports.

You can also find the IP addresses that are cached in Windows by using this command: ipconfig /displaydns

Lastly, they may know how to delete the history, but they might not know how to properly clear caches or cookies, or especially "super cookies".

Of course, there are plenty of third-party tools to help.

Also, depending on who the person is, what they're doing, and your jurisdictions, be mindful that you may find yourself on the defendant side of a courtroom.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'm not worried the jurisdictions, I'm trying to make sure he is not subjecting me to criminal activity.

Comment: That is certainly a good reason to do what you asked about. Unfortunately, prosecutors and judges aren't always reasonable; just fair warning. However, I bid you good luck and hope you find he isn't putting you at risk.

Comment: Thank you again, I appreciate the heads up. I've found myself between a rock and a hard place.  Hey, no good deed goes unpunished, I never understood that statement before.  First time for everything! PEACE!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Hopefully it will also be the last time.  This person doesn't have a right to place you in this position, regardless of their "need". If they are putting you at legal risk, one solution to not putting them out in the street during winter is to put them in a nice, cozy jail cell lest you end up in one yourself. Be strong, and be well. Peace~